# start a macro every day on the same time

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro and i will run that macro automatically, always on the same time on Monday to Friday.
I have already a macro but that runs one time after opening the file.
How to get repeat every day until saterday and sunday?

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim dtmStarttijd As Date
dtmStarttijd = TimeSerial(7, 10, 0)
' Is de macro gestart?
MsgBox "De macro voor het automatisch starten van de procedure is gestart."


Application.OnTime dtmStarttijd, "sDeUitTeVoerenMacro"


End Sub
```

Kind regards
Freek

Comment: have you tried windows task scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

To start a macro at given time and on weekdays should this work:

```
Sub test()
If Weekday(Now, vbMonday) < 6 Then 'check if weekday is < 6, starting by Monday with 1 (Sat = 6, Sun = 7)
Application.OnTime TimeValue("00:01:10"), "YourSub"
End If
End Sub
```

Change `TimeValue("00:01:10")` when the macro should start

Change `"YourSub"` with your sub, e.g. your sub is named `Sub timestart()` put in `"timestart"` (without () but "" are needed!)

Excel has to be started for working

Comment: I have used this macro and its working.                                             There is only one thing, its works only when the workbook is displayed on the screen. When the macro is activated then it starts a another macro. That macro opens another workbooks and start a macro to update data. This is only working when the workbook is visible on the monitor. Is it possible that it update the data when its running on the background (minimized)?

Comment: this is possible but then you need to create a sheduled task

Answer (score 0):

I set mine as scheduled tasks in windows and make it run in a safe mode copy of Excel with a quit at the end of the macro.

Make sure you do workbook.saved = true before quitting to suppress the prompt.